# Get original DateTime offset

Tags: c#, .net

I have following code

```
string dateString = "2018-04-20T12:22:32.8526432-05:30";

var objDate = DateTime.Parse(dateString);  

string newDateString = objDate.ToString();  //"4/20/2018 1:52:32 PM"
```

Once string is parsed to DateTime how do I get original DateTime offset i.e. -5:30 from objDate? I tried following code but it gives local offset i.e. -4:00 but not -5:30.

`var offset = TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.GetUtcOffset(objDate);`

Please note that I want to get offset from DateTime object (objDate) and not from string variable dateString.

Comment: DateTime doesn't store offset, so you can't.

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned by @Evk the `DateTime` type does not store the offset. Instead as suggested by @maccettura

```
string dateString = "2018-04-20T12:22:32.8526432-05:30";
var offset = DateTimeOffset.Parse(dateString);

// returns -05:30:00
Console.WriteLine(offset.Offset);
```